# Почему сжимает контейнер

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Код с таким результатом:

[image: (картинка 1)]

```html
<div class="menu-container">
  <button class="carousel-button" type="button">
    <svg width="16" height="16">
      <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <article class="menu-card">
        <h3 class="menu-title">Pizza</h3>
        <div class="menu-text">
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <article class="menu-card">
        <h3 class="menu-title">Салати</h3>
        <div class="menu-text">
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <article class="menu-card">
        <h3 class="menu-title">Випічка</h3>
        <div class="menu-text">
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="carousel-button" type="button">
    <svg width="16" height="16">
      <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Когда в CSS ввожу:

```css
.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 32px;
}
```

Получаю следующее:

[image: 2ю картинку]

Почему его сжимает?

---

полный код блока

```
<section class="section" id="menu-section">
 <div class="container">
      <h2 class="menus-title section-title centered">Меню</h2>
   <div class="menu-container">
        <button class="carousel-button" type="button">
         <svg width="16" height="16">
          <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <ul class="menu-list">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <article class="menu-card">
          <h3 class="menu-title">Pizza</h3>
        <div class="menu-text">
          <p>Pizza - 30 сантиметрів</p>
          <p>Міні-піца на перекус для одного</p>
          <p>Найкращі начинки. Сирні борти</p>
        </div>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <article class="menu-card">
          <h3 class="menu-title">Салати</h3>
          <div class="menu-text">
          <p>Всі улюбленні салати</p>
          <p>Найсмачніша заправка</p>
          <p>Візьми з собою</p>
        </div>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item">
        <article class="menu-card">
          <h3 class="menu-title">Випічка</h3>
          <div class="menu-text">
          <p>Хачапурі</p>
          <p>Сосиска в тісті</p>
          <p>Кальцоне</p>
        </div>
        </article>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <button class="carousel-button" type="button">
         <svg width="16" height="16">
          <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
        </svg>
      </button>
   </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

весь css

```
 .menu-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 32px;
}
.menu-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}
.menu-item {
  flex-basis: calc((100% - 40px) / 3);
}
.menu-card {
  height: 444px;
  padding: 24px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(49, 38, 26, 0) 55.21%,
    rgba(49, 38, 26, 0.71) 72.92%,
    var(--color-dark) 100%
  );
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.menus-title {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.menu-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.menu-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.carousel-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0;
  fill: var(--color-dark);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-dark);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-button:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-dark);
  fill: var(--color-light);
}
```

Comment: flex-direction: column; - перенес все в столбик

Comment: Потому что флекс по умолчанию сжимает.

Answer (score 1):

> почему его сжимает?

- Во-первых, кроме вертикального выравнивания, есть ещё и горизонтальное распределение - `justify-content`;
- Во-вторых, не указаны размеры блоков. Если размеры "резиновые", то необходимо хотя бы задать поведение - `flex-grow`.

```css
.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 32px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}

.menu-list {
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 32px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}

.menu-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
  <button class="carousel-button" type="button">
    <svg width="16" height="16">
      <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
    </svg>
  </button>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <article class="menu-card">
        <h3 class="menu-title">Pizza</h3>
        <div class="menu-text">
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <article class="menu-card">
        <h3 class="menu-title">Салати</h3>
        <div class="menu-text">
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">
      <article class="menu-card">
        <h3 class="menu-title">Випічка</h3>
        <div class="menu-text">
        </div>
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="carousel-button" type="button">
    <svg width="16" height="16">
      <use href="/images/icon.svg#icon-Arrow-1"></use>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: justify-content: center; - просто выравнивает по центру, но все равно зауженые карточки.
размеры есть:

Comment: @user576505, Вы сделали, как в моём примере или выборочно? И где какие размеры? Дополните свой вопрос и приведите все стили, которые относятся к предоставленной разметке. А то "партизанщина" какая-то...